# Как сделать двухстороннюю привязку данных по клику?

Tags: angular

Я только начал изучать Angular, уже столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно связать `input` и `p` по клику. Чтобы данные, введенные в `input` выводились в `p` по клику на кнопку.

**main**

```
        <div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="names" /></div>
 <br/>
    <div>  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="age" /></div>

    <app-child [userName]="names" [userAge]="age"></app-child>
    <button (click)=???>Click</button>
```

**child**

```
<p>UserName: {{userName}}</p>
<p>Age: {{userAge}}</p>
```

В .ts файлах у меня только объявление переменных, и использование директивы Input.

Спасибо большое заранее!

Comment: Т.е. хотите чтобы значения передавались именно по клику? А не сразу как сейчас

Answer (score 0):

По-моему два адекватных варианта - делать сабджект да прокидовать его параметром в чайлд или же сервис, на котором будет тот же сабджект.